# Expressing e as an infinite series: finding values for similar series

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

I am supposed to be using the fact that $e = \sum_{n=0} ^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$ to find the value of $\sum_{n=0} ^\infty \frac{1}{2n!}$.

Is there some method for substitution when dealing with infinite series, like how we have with arithmetic or functions? Every proof that I've seen for the above identity concerning $e$ is very specific for $e$, and I don't see how to provide a similar proof to find a value for $2n!$.

Comment: You probably mean $(2n)!$ in the denominator, right? (Normal precedence rules are that $2n! = 2(n!)$, and then your series would just be $e/2$).

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I typed incorrectly. Correcting now. That is far more simple than I expected it to be. So, I should be able to show by simple arithmetic of factorials and sigma notation (pulling the $1/2$ out of the summation) that we have $e/2$ as our answer. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful ..because $(2n)!\neq 2(n!)$ in general. So which one are you looking for?

Comment: Shouldn't it be though? Can you not say that $(2n)!=(2n)*(2(n-1))*(2(n-2))*...=2*(n)*(n-1)*(n-2)*...=2*(n!)$?

Comment: No, It should be $$(2n)! = 2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdots 1$$

Answer (score 3):

If you're allowed to use $e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$, then look at the expression for $e^1 + e^{-1}$ (assuming Lukas Geyer is correct in his comment above).